# Build Failed Could not find method signingConfigs()

Tags: android, react-native

I follow in official website : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

it said line: 128 error
which is
`signingConfigs signingConfigs.release`

in android/app/build.gradle

```
 signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfigs signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

in android/.gradle/gradle.properties

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=ezam.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=ezam
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=*****
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=*****
```

Answer (score 26):

Honestly spend 3 hours on this issue

```
buildTypes{
    release{
        signingConfig  // not signingConfigs without "s"
    }
}
```

Comment: You save my life.

Comment: another life been saved today

Answer (score 11):

The `signingConfigs` element must be a child of the `android` element

```
apply plugin 'com.android.application'

android {

    // (...)

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            // (...)
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // (...)
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

I experienced the same error because I didn't realise this, and made `signingConfigs` a top-level element.

This will give you an error:

```
apply plugin 'com.android.application'

signingConfigs {
    release {
        // (...)
    }
}


android {

    // (...)

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // (...)
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That saved my life, this should be better pointed out in the docs.

Comment: Thanks this helped me too

Answer (score 5):

You are adding the config to the wrong file. Add it to app level build.gradle android/app/build.gradle.

see https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher/issues/228#issuecomment-321557581

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Links to external resources are encouraged, but always quote the most relevant parts of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I have to do

```
buildTypes{
    release{
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

instead of

```
buildTypes{
    release{
        signingConfig release
    }
}
```